# Is Batman: Strange Apparitions part of the post-Crisis Year One main continuity, and if so, why?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, continuity

*Batman: Strange Apparitions* is a 1999 collection of Len Wein/Steve Englehart stories that were originally published in the 1970s.

I've seen mention online of these pre-*Crisis on Infinite Earths* tales being retrospectively considered canon in the **post-*Crisis*/pre-*Flashpoint Batman: Year One*** main timeline/continuity.

Does anybody have any knowledge about the reasons for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a full discussion of Hugo Strange's convoluted history in the comic books, Pre-Crisis and Post-Crisis, you should examine [**"Timeline: The Shifting Continuity of Hugo Strange."**](http://www.cbr.com/lorendiacs-timeline-the-shifting-continuity-of-hugo-strange/) It was researched and written, years ago, by a longtime fan of Batman comic books who usually posts online under the catchy name of "Lorendiac." (Gosh, doesn't that name sound oddly familiar, as if I've seen it before, somewhere?)

Seriously, though . . . I am, in fact, the same guy who wrote that old piece. Back in the early-to-mid 2000s, I participated in some lively debates, in online comic book forums, regarding the very point you are asking about. Was Hugo Strange's Pre-Crisis continuity still valid in the Post-Crisis version of the DCU (i.e. for the version of Batman who had Frank Miller's "Year One" as his Official Origin Story), or wasn't it? I thought I knew the answer, but was startled to find that some of my fellow fans vigorously disagreed with my interpretation!

So I finally took the plunge and dug out *every* Hugo Strange story I could find in my collection, and reread them, taking careful notes on anything I might need to use as evidence, so that I could write and post The Definitive Answer to the question of how (or if) his continuity had changed.

Here's the Short Answer: **All** of Hugo Strange's Pre-Crisis continuity seems to have been erased from Batman's history in the fallout from the Crisis on Infinite Earths . . . but this fact did not become *crystal-clear* to the typical buyer of Batman comic books until a certain story was published in the year **2000.**

If you want to see *all* the messy details which led me to draw that conclusion, it would help to read my old piece. But since we're not supposed to post "Answers" which are little more than posted links to something on another website, I will now try to elaborate a bit with a bare-bones summary of the crucial facts:

1. The last "Pre-Crisis" appearance of Hugo Strange was in *Batman Annual #10*, published in 1986, and clearly set before the regular Batman title switched over to stories set in the revamped, Post-Crisis version of the DCU. This story (by Doug Moench) explicitly referenced Hugo's last appearance before that (*Batman #356*, in 1983) which in turn had explicitly explained how Hugo had recovered from the apparent "death" in the 1970s -- that's the same one depicted in the "Strange Apparitions" TPB.
2. After this, the next comic book appearance of Hugo Strange was in the five-part story arc "Prey," published in the comic book series *Legends of the Dark Knight* (in late 1990 and early 1991, according to the cover dates). "Prey" told a whole new version of how Batman and Hugo Strange "first met," early in Batman's career, with a plot which *blatantly contradicted* all previous Hugo Strange continuity.
3. However! It was not crystal-clear whether this meant "Hugo Strange has just been Officially Rebooted," because "Legends of the Dark Knight" repeatedly *warned* its readers, in the letter columns, that its stories were *not necessarily* part of the standard Batman continuity of that era. The general idea was to let the writer of each new story arc let his imagination run wild *without worrying* about whether or not his story was contradicting a bunch of other "canonical" stories in some of the fine points. In other words, the "Prey" story arc was not necessarily the "new and improved" Official Post-Crisis Doctrine regarding how Hugo Strange first became interested in the mystery of "Who is Batman?" The events of "Prey" might turn out to be canonical . . . or it might not . . . but only time would tell!
4. Then, almost a decade rolled past (the rest of the 1990s, basically) *without* any definitely-canonical appearances of Hugo Strange in *any* new comic books. As far as I know, between 1991 and 2000, Hugo Strange literally was *never mentioned* in so much as a single line of dialogue in any "canonical" Batman stories. So all through the 1990s, nobody knew if "Prey" had "really happened" in the Post-Crisis continuity (what you call the "Year One" continuity) . . . or not!
5. Then, late in the year **2000**, in the series *Gotham Knights* (which was part of the ongoing continuity of that era) a new four-part story arc began. It was called "Transference." In it, Hugo Strange was making a big comeback after a long dry spell. Dialogue between Hugo and Batman explicitly referenced the events of "Prey" as being the *last time* Hugo had been reported as doing anything at all in Gotham City. Since "Prey" had clearly been written as a story about the **first** clash between Hugo and Batman, and now "Transference" was supposed to be only the *second* time they had fought each other (many years after "Prey"), the inescapable implication was that all Pre-Crisis stories about Hugo (including the ones in "Strange Apparitions") had *never happened* to the Post-Crisis version of Batman. (Which would certainly explain why those events had never been *mentioned* in dialogue in any of those Post-Crisis adventures!)
6. However! After "Infinite Crisis" ended in 2006, with some changes to the DCU chronology, Grant Morrison got cracking on a long run as a Batman writer, and in 2007 he had Batman refer to Hugo Strange's old "Monster Serum." That chemical concoction, turning ordinary men into huge, muscular monster-men, had been used in one of Hugo Strange's Golden Age appearances (1940), and again in Englehart's "Strange Apparitions" material, but not in any later Hugo Strange stories (such as "Prey" or "Transference"). So the implication was that, as far as Grant Morrison was concerned, the Post-Infinite Crisis version of Batman had, in fact, experienced at least some of the Pre-Crisis stories which pitted him against Hugo Strange.

To summarize: From **1986** through **2006** (in other words, from the end of "Crisis on Infinite Earths" to the end of "Infinite Crisis"), the stuff about Hugo Strange in "Strange Apparitions" had never happened, and was *never mentioned,* in any new comic books released by DC. A story published in **2000** made it clear that "Prey" (from 1990-1991) had replaced all previous material as "the new and improved version of Batman's previous interaction with Hugo Strange." In **2007,** Post-Infinite Crisis, it was made clear that some or all of the Pre-Crisis Hugo material was "canonical" once again!

(However, I have lost track of Batman's continuity in recent years -- in the New 52 version, for instance -- so I honestly don't know what Hugo's *current* continuity is supposed to be. Fortunately, you weren't asking about that!)

Comment: Lorendiac, many _many_ thanks! Exactly what I was after (I've read the linked article too). From comments I've read I understand the done thing here is to wait a bit before ticking an answer as 'most useful' in case something else comes along - but given the level of research you've put in I can't see that being likely. I'll give it a couple of days - but I fully expect to be coming back to tick this! Thanks again.

Comment: @Gray: thanks are best communicated with up-votes!

Comment: @Paul D. Waite Up-voted!